# Preserving type (int or float) of entry when extracting rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I append several rows to containing elements of different type (either float or integer):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.append( pd.DataFrame({'i': [0],
                              'j': [0.3]}), ignore_index=True)

df = df.append( pd.DataFrame({'i': [1],
                              'j': [0.6]}), ignore_index=True)

df = df.append( pd.DataFrame({'i': [9],
                              'j': [0.9]}), ignore_index=True)
```

Now, I want to extract the row that contains the smallest value of, say, `i`:

```
df.iloc[df['i'].argmin()]
```

This gives me

```
i    0.0
j    0.3
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

where `i` has now been converted to a float. This is very undesirable for me ad I would like for it to stay an integer.

Is there a way to perform the `iloc` such that the type is unchanged? Or a way to define `df` initially such that it respects the type of each column?

Note that I would prefer a solution that does not assume I know in advance which columns will be interger and which will be float. All I know is that columns will exist of those two types.

---

EDIT: Say I now want to convert the result to a dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df = df.append( pd.DataFrame({'i': [0],
                              'j': [0.3]}), ignore_index=True)

df = df.append( pd.DataFrame({'i': [0],
                              'j': [0.3]}), ignore_index=True)            

df = df.iloc[df['i'].idxmin()].astype(object)            
df.astype(object).to_dict()
```

This gives me `{'i': 0.0, 'j': 0.3}`. The form of the dictionary is as desired, however, the integer has now turned into a float. Is it possible to preserve the `int`-format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argmin` has been deprecated, use `idxmin` with `loc`.

What is happening is that you used a scalar to slice and getting a Series in return.  That series will have a single dtype.  Instead, slice with a list or array.

```
# notice the extra set of brackets
df.loc[[df['i'].idxmin()]]

   i    j
0  0  0.3
```

This tells Pandas that you want a data frame back.

---

If you wanted `argmin`

```
df.iloc[[df['i'].values.argmin()]]
```

---

Simplest way to create the dict

```
dict(next(df.iloc[[df['i'].values.argmin()]].itertuples(index=False))._asdict())
```

Or

```
{k: v[0] for k, v in df.iloc[[df['i'].values.argmin()]].items()}
```

Comment: When I use `to_dict` the dtype of the `int`-column changes to float - why is that?

Comment: Several places you could use `to_dict`.  Show me the whole expression you ran.

Comment: Remember that when you call the `iloc` with a scalar as you originally did and as you do with Wen's answer `df.iloc[df['i'].idxmin()].astype(object)` that is a series object and can only have one dtype.  When you use `object` as that dtype, you can mask other problems.  Pandas will format a float that is equal to an integer as if it were an integer.  You really need to call it as I've shown to preserve the dtypes.

Comment: Thanks. That gives me a dictionary with the form `{'i': {0: 0}, 'j': {0: 0.3}}`. Is it possible to remove the initial `0:` that comes in each value such that I end up with a dictionary with the form `{'i': 0.0, 'j': 0.3}`

Answer (score 3):

Try to fix your output

```
df.iloc[df['i'].idxmin()].astype(object)
Out[1480]: 
i      0
j    0.3
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this out and it works - when I convert the result to a dictionary though, it still converts the int to a float (see my OP)

Comment: @N08 then you can just follow pir’s suggestion :-)